# How do I put an image on the Clipboard?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clipboard

I'm using WinForms alongside a WinForms version of ChartFX, and trying to convert the chart to a Metafile and place it in the clipboard. I'm ceratain the Metafile is being created correctly in the below code, but when I copy in the application and try to paste in another it's unsuccessfuly.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    chart1.Export(FileFormat.Metafile, memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    var metaFileImage = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);

    var dataObj = new DataObject();
    dataObj.SetData(DataFormats.EnhancedMetafile, metaFileImage);

    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
}
```

How can I correctly copy the Metafile to the clipboard? I have also tried Clipboard.SetImage(metaFileImage); which converted it to a bitmap. I've even tried Clipboard.SetData(metaFileImage.GetType().FullName, metaFileImage); but it's doing the same as the original code?

Annoyingly, you can do this from ChartFX's toolbar, but they do not expose any of the commands so I can't invoke it when a user press Ctrl+C.

Comment: Have you tried `DataFormats.MetafilePict`?

Comment: Does this have any bearing on your situation:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323530

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I had tried it, but the outcome was the same.

Comment: @DonBoitnott You're right, that's nailed it! Add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this explains what is happening in your situation as well:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323530